# Get file content and make a list

Tags: python

I am a newbie trying to get the content in a file and make a list from it.

I want to print "There is no item." when the file is empty, and "You have xxx."(xxx being the item name) when there is only one string in the file (e.g. 'banana').

```
Content of my_file.txt:
banana,mango,peach,apple


with open("my_file.txt", "r+") as f:
    items = f.read()
    items = items.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
    items = items.split(",")
    last_item = items[-1]
    items_ex_last_item = items[:-1]
    print("You have " + ', '.join(items_ex_last_item) + " and " + last_item + ".")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) filters out empty strings. Then `if` checks if the remaining list is empty. If not empty, checks length and prints accordingly.

```
with open("my_text_file.txt", "r") as f:
    items = f.read()
    items = items.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
    items = items.split(",")

    items = [i for i in items if i]
    if items:

        if len(items) == 1:
            print('You have {}'.format(items[0]))

        if len(items) > 1:
            last_item = items[-1]
            items_ex_last_item = items[:-1]
            print("You have " + ', '.join(items_ex_last_item) + " and " + last_item + ".")

    else:
        print("There is no item.")
```

---

`items = [i for i in items if i]` is the equivalent of the following code:

```
new_lst = []
for i in items:
    if i:
        new_lst.append(i)
items = new_lst
```

Loops through all elements in `items` list, and checks `if i` is True. If it is, then it will `append()` it into the list. Finally, it makes `items` refer to the `new_lst`, effectively replacing `items`' old contents.

How `if x:` works ([link](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)):

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: False, None, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next` which will raise a `StopIteration` which in this case will signify the file is empty, and use tuple unpacking to get items until the last, and the last item, then decide what to print based on that, eg:

```
with open('my_file.txt') as fin:
    try:
        *items, last = next(fin).split(',')
        if not items: print('You have', last)
        else: print('You have', ', '.join(items) + ' and ' + last)
    except StopIteration:
        print('No items')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

with open('my_file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    res = '\n'.join(
        'You have {} ({})'.format(v, k)
        for k, v in sorted(
            Counter(f.read().strip().split(',')),
            key=itemgetter(1, 0), reverse=True)
    )
    print res if res else 'There is no item'
```